# How could I make this question less broad?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

I just had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198115/1091116) put on hold because it seems too broad. I had the feeling that it would make a good question about the limitations of `cgo` and don't really understand what's wrong about it. Could anyone explain that to me?

Comment: We can't really tell you how to make it less broad.  There are millions of more specific questions that could be covered under the umbrella of that question, we can't possibly know what you actually want to know.  *You* have to be the one to come up with a more specific question.

Comment: What I wanted to know are technical limitations of `cgo` in context of the ones I can come across when trying to partially port a C application to Go. Where's the uncertainity there?

Comment: There's no uncertainty.  Your question isn't unclear, it's too broad.

Comment: Where's the line then? I have seem quite a lot highly upvoted general questions that have elaborate answers. I'm a bit lost at when it's appropriate and when not.

Comment: What kind of answers do you expect to that question and how will they not require multiple paragraphs to even touch the subject?

Comment: You can start by specifying exactly what portions of your C program you are intending to port. (That alone isn't enough to narrow it down completely, but it's a start.)

Comment: @BoltClock: I mentioned that it's a command line program and that I'm interested in compatibility/interactions between `cgo` and things like inline assembly or IPC.

Comment: @d33tah The line is whether a complete answer to the question can be posted in a paragraph or two.  The question your asking couldn't conceivably be given a *complete* answer even with several pages of text.

Comment: @d33tah: Your phrasing appears to be open-ended. "things like..." while not being exhaustive. It sounds like a nitpick, but the fact is that people don't seem to tolerate that sort of thing.

Comment: Your question says `and in my opinion`, `What should I watch out for?` and `What should I expect to be a problem?`.  The entire question is irredeemably broad.  There is no change that you can make to make it less broad.  You really should not have asked it in the first place if you are worried about down votes.  If you have a specific question then ask it.  This one is beyond saving.